# How can I trace what happens during XAML loading?

Tags: debugging, xaml, logging

I would like to find a way to see what happens while my XAML is being loaded. What classes are being instantiated, and in what order? Which properties are being set, to what values, and in what order? Which methods are being called (e.g. BeginInit, EndInit, etc.), in what order, and with what parameters? That sort of thing.

(If anyone's curious as to why, it's because the XAML loader is doing something magic that I [can't duplicate in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056021/creating-a-croppedbitmap-at-runtime-wont-load-from-resource), and I'm trying to figure out what it is.)

- My first idea: [Configure VS to debug into the .NET source code](http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx), and single-step through the XAML-loading code to see what happens. Unfortunately, [source stepping has been busted for months, and there's no sign of that changing.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/refsourceserver/thread/c161b368-5fc6-4fa9-9bea-df3c73d8c101)
- My second idea: Make my own classes that descend from WPF classes, override [OnPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.onpropertychanged.aspx), and do a Debug.WriteLine. Unfortunately, one of the classes I want to know about ([BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx)) is sealed, so I can't descend from it.

Anyone have other ideas on how I could get some visibility into what the XAML loader is doing? Are there any tools (profiler, maybe?) that could give me a call graph? Is there a way to turn on some kind of logging in the XAML loader? Thoughts / suggestions?

---

**Edit:** The article Steve linked to does have the answer, though their sample code makes every event get displayed twice. For reference, here's how to make this work in code (no app.config changes required). Add these lines before the InitializeComponent() call (or type both lines into the Immediate window in the debugger):

```
PresentationTraceSources.Refresh();
PresentationTraceSources.MarkupSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.All;
```

This will cause detailed output to show up in VS's Output window, including the properties that get set magically behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trace a lot of the binding and loading with [system.diagnostics](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/14/WpfTraceSources.aspx). I've found a number of problems using this namespace. Its unwieldy like everything else in WPF, but it works. You can see what's getting set and where.